# Running Jasmine inside the Mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, tdd, bdd, jasmine, mongo-shell

My collection of admin utilities for MongoDB is growing and it's time to put some regression tests in place. I could use the assert-type functionality that is used in the built-in Mongo testing helpers but I'm a big fan of RSpec & Jasmine and would rather write tests in that style. I do not require automation, simply the ability to write test using Jasmine, run them from the shell and see the results.

Has anyone gotten Jasmine working inside the Mongo shell? If not, any tips for what I need to mock/shim in order to make Jasmine happy in that environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's doable but not straight-forward. You could take the Node.js version of Jasmine which shows which browser objects Jasmine depends on, e.g., window, and fake them.

I decided it was too much work and used the assert-type functions that 10gen uses internally--they are available in the Mongo shell.

For example, type `assert` in the Mongo shell prompt:

```
> assert
function (b, msg) {
    if (assert._debug && msg) {
        print("in assert for: " + msg);
    }
    if (b) {
        return;
    }
    doassert(msg == undefined ? "assert failed" : "assert failed : " + msg);
}
```